# How to update facebook page?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

I am a PHP developer who was asked by a client to update their Facebook business page with changing statistics. Not by posting the information as status updates at an interval, but to update the Facebook page description like AJAX would update a page view counter. Is this possible? Can you point me in the right direction of how to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to [authenticate](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/)  your application ([this is also good reading here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/access-tokens-and-types/)) and ask for [extended_permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/permissions-login-dialog/), specifically the `manage_pages` permission.

This allows your application to [login as a page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-as-page/).

Then you can modify certain parts of the [page attributes](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#attributes).

There is a nice class available on [phpclasses.org](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/7700-PHP-Authorize-and-access-APIs-using-OAuth.html) to aid in logging in with facebook, though their own [PHP SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/) is really nice when you get used to it.

Good luck!